# Google Webmaster Tools show only common words in the keywords list

Tags: google-search-console, keywords

I have a greek site with greek domain (gr) and even so, the keyword list of google shows in the first places the greek equivalent words of the common words like "in", "a", "and",etc.
All them would be greek's Stop Words 
Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you talking about "Optimization" -> "Content Keywords" or "Traffic" -> "Search Queries"?

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools/optimization/content keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Greek site has similar data.  My top keywords under "Optimization" -> "Content Keywords" are το, για, and της, the Greek words for it, for, and of.

I've spot checked my site in several other languages.  Spanish, Italian, and Arabic don't appear to exhibit this behavior.

This appears to be a bug in Google Webmaster Tools.  It appears that for Greek sites, they are not properly identifying important words compared to common words.  Since this issue affects multiple Greek sites, I wouldn't worry to much about it.  Google should be able to fix it at some point.  In Webmaster Tools you could tell Google about this problem using "Help" -> "Send Feedback".

Comment: Thanks Stephen! That not solve the problem but your answer save a lot of time of research. Thanks a lot